# Why is the toolbox empty on VS 2010 shell used by SQL Server data tools?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I installed SQL Server 2012 and I imported my old SSIS projects into it. Everything is fine but when I tried to edit my package, surprisingly the toolbox is empty on the SQL Server Data Tools, and I have no idea how to bring those items back. Can anybody help?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which version did you install? Just the core?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Click **`SSIS`** menu --> **`SSIS Toolbox`** to view the SSIS specific toolbox on *`SQL Server Data Tools`* (previously known as *Business Intelligence Development Studio*).

The toolbox shown in the screenshot of the question is related to Visual Studio toolbox, which can be found under **`View`**  menu --> **`Toolbox`** . This is different from the SSIS Toolbox.

[image: SSIS Toolbox]

Comment: Applies to VS 2013 and SSDT-BI as well.

Comment: I wonder why it's not there by default - 3.5 years after this post?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with 2012 (SQL Server data tools). See James post here:
http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2013/01/ssis-2012-empty-toolbox/

apparently there is a button (that doesn't appear in the menus)

I actually got so frustrated that I reinstalled SSDT; which fixed the problem for about a week, then I broke it again. Google search returned this post on top, so I'm re-posting.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and there are two way to fix this problem very fast.

The first ones : open one of our package in top right of your package there are two buttons one of them is "variables" and second ones is "SSIS Toolbox". Press the second ones : "SSIS Toolbox".

[image]

The second way as user user756519 has said in above is selecting SSIS menu in VS and select SSIS ToolBox.

[image]